# How to query all Parents with the sum of an attribute on their Children?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a Rails app I have two models as follows

```
class Trip 
  has_many :items
  # has a 'fuel' column
end
class Item
  belongs_to :trip
  # has a 'quantity' column 
end
```

For a dashboard view, I need to aggregate these data so they can be presented in a chart.

The following method produces the correct output

```
def self.to_dashboard_chart
  data = [['Fuel', 'Quantity']]
  self.all.each do |trip|
    data << [trip.fuel, trip.items.sum(:quantity)] unless trip.fuel.nil?
  end
  data
end
```

but is also terribly inefficient, especially when the database becomes large!

I am trying to adapt this to a single query.

```
def self.to_dashboard_chart_new
  self.joins(:items).
    where.not(fuel: nil).
    select("fuel, sum(items.quantity) as trip_quantity").
    group(:id).
    map{ |t| [t.fuel, t.trip_quantity] }.
    unshift(['Fuel','Quantity'])
end
```

However this is not returning an equal response

```
Trip.to_dashboard_chart == Trip.to_dashboard_chart_new 
=> false
Trip.to_dashboard_chart.length == Trip.to_dashboard_chart_new.length
=> false
```

I can't see why these are returning different results. What am I overlooking?

## EDIT

I think I've tracked down the problem to how Trips with no Items are handled.

```
let!(:t1) { create :trip, fuel: 50 }
let!(:t2) { create :trip, fuel: 100 }
let!(:t3) { create :trip, fuel: 200 }
let!(:t4) { create :trip, fuel: nil }

let!(:i1)  { create :item, trip: t1, quantity: 10 }
let!(:i2)  { create :item, trip: t1, quantity: 20 }
let!(:i3)  { create :item, trip: t2, quantity: 50 } 

it "returns the correct response with old" do
  expect(Trip.to_dashboard_chart_old).to eq(
        [
          ["Fuel", "Quantity"],
          [50,30],
          [100,50],
          [200,0]
        ]
      )
end

it "returns the correct response with new" do
  expect(Trip.to_dashboard_chart_new).to eq(
        [
          ["Fuel", "Quantity"],
          [50,30],
          [100,50],
          [200,0]
        ]
      )
end
```

`Trip.to_dashboard_chart_old` passes, whereas `Trip.to_dashboard_chart_new` fails with

```
expected: [["Fuel", "Quantity"], [50, 30], [100, 50], [200, 0]]
got: [["Fuel", "Quantity"], [50, 30], [100, 50]]
```

How should I modify the query to ensure that a quantity of `0` is returned for Trips that do not have any Items?

Comment: Can you show us the final output of that two queries?

Comment: You group by id in your query, but not in the first version it seems. Could it be that ?

Comment: I just rewrote your code, and found `Trip.to_dashboard_chart == Trip.to_dashboard_chart_new` is `true`

Comment: I think the order of data turned out to be different, try using default scope with `order` of your choice `asc` or ` desc`.

Comment: @illusionist the length is not equal also. So no, it's not an ordering issue.

Comment: @illusionist thanks for suggestions. I think I've tracked the problem to the way that Trips with no Items are handled. Please see edits above. Grateful for any further suggestions your may have.

Comment: @GrahamSlick I don't think it is the grouping. Actually I don't really need to group, but grouping by ID should just return the complete collection, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def self.to_dashboard_chart_my
  arr = [['Fuel','Quantity']]
  items = self.left_outer_joins(:items).
    where('trips.fuel is not null').
    select("fuel, COALESCE(sum(items.quantity),0) as trip_quantity").
    group(:id)

  for item in items do
     arr << [item.fuel, item.trip_quantity]
  end

  arr
end
```

### Bechmarks IPS(Iterations per seconds)

```
Warming up --------------------------------------
            Your One   148.000  i/100ms
              My one   165.000  i/100ms
Calculating -------------------------------------
            Your One      1.461k (±10.3%) i/s -      7.252k in   5.052092s
              My one      1.676k (± 8.8%) i/s -      8.250k in   5.004467s
```

Comment: Interesting! Benchmarking on a large dataset, your code gave elapsed real time of 1.17 s. My code gave 1.16 s on the first run, and 1.19 s on the second run. :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, after much head scratching, I eventually figured out that the problem was how the query was handling Trips with no Items.

Changing `joins` to `left_outer_joins` ensures that all records are included, and adding `COALESCE` to the `SUM` function ensures that `0` is returned instead of `nil`.

```
def self.to_dashboard_chart_new
  self.left_outer_joins(:items).
    where.not(fuel: nil).
    select("fuel, COALESCE(sum(items.quantity),0) as trip_quantity").
    group(:id).
    map{ |t| [t.fuel, t.trip_quantity] }.
    unshift(['Fuel','Quantity'])
end
```

Performance is much better! In a database with 50,000 records

```
puts Benchmark.measure { Trip.to_dashboard_chart_old }
44.170000   3.960000  48.130000 ( 80.253821)
puts Benchmark.measure { Trip.to_dashboard_chart_new }
0.920000   0.030000   0.950000 (  1.412365)
```

If anyone can come up with an even more performant query, I'd be happy to mark it as the correct answer.